# Проблема с кешированием сайта ВордПресс - как исправить?

Tags: wordpress, login

У меня проблема с входом на сайт вордпресс, связанная с кешированием. Когда я очищаю кэш, она исчезает примерно на сутки, потом снова появляется, плагин кэширования у меня LiteSpeed ​​Cache. Подскажите, как это исправить -  возможно, время кэширования изменить или что-то ещё?

Comment: Попробуйте другой плагин кэширования

Answer (score 0):

Сервер на котором я работаю работает с этим плагином в cPanel поэтому в последнюю очередь хочется менять плагин кеширования